# How to translate XSLT into (partial) PHP?

Tags: php, xslt

Due to a work I need done, I need to do a translation between two different programs.
A program defines data translations as XSLT and the other program uses a different format.
The program in between was chosen to be written in PHP.
I have no possible saying or vote on what is above for reasons I'm not allowed to tell.

The XSLT used is a small subset of all tags that are defined for XSLT:

```
for-each, if, choose, value-of
```

For those, I can just do a simple handling with a switch.
My main issue, though, is the when@test. The program may use any of XSLT's functions.

Now, the number of functions that XSLT has is very extensive and it seems that reproducing or mapping all of those one-by-one is a wrong way to solve this.  Is there any better way of translating XSLT's functions into PHP functions (not necessarily php native functions) that I'm failing to find?

I already tied looking at the XSLTProcessor class but it doesn't seem to have any way of achieving what I want...

NOTE: Currently I'm reading the XSLT with PHP's DOMDocument object.

Comment: Why on earth would you need to do that? Also, I do not fully understand: What kind of program do you currently have? XSLT? PHP? If the PHP script is in-between, what is the "other program using a different format"? Why translate anything if you can execute XSLT transformations in PHP, as you know?

Comment: IMHO you are asking the wrong question. Instead of trying to map individual instructions from one language to another - which is not likely to lead up to anything useful - you should ask (1) what does this XSLT program do? and (2) what is the best way to implement the same functionality in PHP (or in a third language - you're not being entirely clear on this point)?

Comment: @MathiasMüller I have XSLT and the third one. It is chosen that the one in the middle is in PHP. I can't control any of that and I can only work with the XSLT

Comment: @michael.hor257k The 1st program define transformations of data(A) based on other data (B) I'm not allowed to access. I need to use (A) and translate it into data(C) which is what program C can fully understand. At least, at this point, I can't tell what C does with it. I can infer some things from its interface but, unfortunately, I can't reveal it...

Comment: If you cannot give any information about your problem, i.e. cannot show the XSLT stylesheet, cannot describe clearly what it should do, cannot say why you need to translate to another language, why there must be PHP in between (...) - then I'm sure nobody can help you.

Comment: @MathiasMüller OK. Thank you for trying, then. I can tell which functionalities of the XSLT it outputs but all the rest is confidential... This sucks...

Comment: I understand this even less now than before. Are you trying to move data or logic? The former is easy - provided you know what you have on this side and what you need to have on the other side. The latter is IMHO not feasible.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The former. It is feasible... How hard it is... I'm unsure. PHP is turring complete and XSLT is not, so PHP can do everything that XSLT does ;).

Comment: Not that it matters here, but [XSLT **is** Turing-complete](http://www.unidex.com/turing/utm.htm). Now, if you're trying to move data, and your original data is XML, and you want to transform it from one XML schema to another, then XSLT is the tool of choice for this task. And it can transform from schema A to schema C directly, with no need for middleware.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the info on XSLT. I was unsure. The information I have is only XSLT, not something for it to transform. I already started a discussion to decide what to do about this because I can't work without enough info and produce quality results.

Comment: "*The information I have is only XSLT, not something for it to transform.*" Then you have nothing to do. XSLT is logic, not data.

Comment: @michael.hor257k My main idea would be a translation from XSLT to PHP the same way you can translate java into phython... Sounds like that's not a even a remotely viable way, just as I thought.

Comment: *Can* you translate Java into Python? I don't know. At least they are both imperative languages, - [XSLT is not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Declarative_languages). So no, I don't think that's viable. Not to mention that when it comes to processing XML data, the standard way in PHP is to call for an XSL transformation (as stated in the first comment above).

Comment: @michael.hor257k "Can you translate Java into Python?". Sure. I already did that previously. It wasn't a long work, anyway. It was just a small subset